# How is findById() + save() different from update() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

While trying to update a MongoDB document using Mongoose, can I use a `findById()` with a `save()` in the callback, or should I stick with traditional update methods such as `findByIdAndModify`, `findOneAndModify`, `update()`, etc.? Say I want to update the `name` field of the following document (*please see a more elaborate example in the edit at the end, which motivated my question*):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("123"),
    "name": "Development"
}
```

(Mongoose model name for the collection is `Category`)

I could do this:

```
Category.update({ "_id" : "123" }, { "name" : "Software Development" }, { new: true })
```

or I could do this:

```
Category.findById("123", function(err, category) {
    if (err) throw err;
    category.name = "Software Development";
    category.save();
});
```

For more elaborate examples, it feels easier to manipulate a JavaScript object that can simply be saved, as opposed to devising a relatively complex update document for the `.update()` operation. Am I missing something fundamentally important?

**Edited 7/21/2016** Responding to the comment from @Cameron, I think a better example is warranted:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("123"),
    "roles": [{
        "roleId": ObjectId("1234"),
        "name": "Leader"
    }, {
        "roleId": ObjectId("1235"),
        "name": "Moderator"
    }, {
        "roleId": ObjectId("1236"),
        "name": "Arbitrator"
    }]
}
```

What I am trying to do is remove some roles as well as add some roles in the `roles` array of sub-documents in a single operation. To add role sub-documents, `$push` can be used and to remove role sub-documents, `$pull` is used. But if I did something like this:

```
Person.update({
    "_id": "123"
}, {
    $pull : {
        "roles" : {
            "roleId" : {
                $in : [ "1235", "1236" ]
            }
        }
    },
    $push : {
        "roles" : {
            $each: [{
                "roleId" : ObjectId("1237"),
                "name" : "Developer"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute this, I get the error `Cannot update 'roles' and 'roles' at the same time`, of course. That's when I felt it is easier to find a document, manipulate it any way I want and then save it. In that scenario, I don't know if there is really any other choice for updating the document.

Comment: Aside from atomicity concerns, why make two round-trips to the database when you can do it with just one?

Comment: @Cameron I updated with a more elaborate sample document and desired operations which form the basis for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically like to use `findById()` when I am performing more elaborate updates and don't think you are missing anything fundamentally important.

However one method to be aware of in mongoose is `findByIdAndUpdate()`, this issues a mongodb `findAndModify` update command and  would allow you to perform your first example with the following code: `Category.findByIdAndUpdate("123", function(err, savedDoc) {...})`.

Comment: I looked at `findByIdAndUpdate()` too, but one of the constraints is that the update must be performed if a specific query condition is met, which goes beyond finding the document by its ID value alone.